# AKKA.NET with Asp.net web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api, akka.net

We are planning to develop  an audit service web api using AKKA.NET .

The API will receive the audit log data and  will spawn an **Audit actor** which will do some security checks , insert the data in to a database  and  sent a email notification in case of any major security breaches. The plan is to use TELL method to do the processing in a fire and forget mechanism . The API will always return 200 OK so that calling service is not affected.

When we did some research , we found that most of the  posts suggest creating a static instance of **ActorSystem** in global.asax,   we found 2 ways of creaing an actor

1. Spawn an actor [with unique names] , inside the API and **initiate a new instance of the Actor for every call and call the Tell method**
2. Create a **single static instance of the Actor** and call the Tell Method

We feel the approach 2 is the best way to leverage AKKA.NET. Are we on the right path?

Comment: Do the actors have state?

Comment: No  there issue no state it will just insert the data and send a email

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would normally go for option 1 in this type of scenario. You need to think about how you handle failure. I would probably create some sort of supervisor actor to handle this process each time you get a command to do it. The supervisor could then create and supervise (i.e. determine how failure is handled) two actors - one for saving to the DB, another to send the email. The supervisor would be responsible for managing the process and killing itself (and children) when finished.

If you go for the second option, you will have a single queue for all messages so you will run into problems with scaling. You could get around this by having a pool of Actors , but I think it will be more difficult to handle retries and failures, especially if you need to know which things have been saved but didn't send emails. You could probably still get it to work, especially if you don't care if the save-then-email process fully completes, but I just think the first option fits the Actor model better.

Comment: Will creating 3 actor for each api call next an overhead... also I may need to kill these actor after process was completed.. I qmlittle confused..in such scenarios how are we leveraging AKKA. Net..also on d

Comment: Actors are pretty cheap to create so unless you have a very high volume of traffic I wouldnt worry about this. However, as with any performance question, you should measure and monitor

Comment: In terms of killing the Actors, you can call Stop() when the process has finished. See https://petabridge.com/blog/how-to-stop-an-actor-akkadotnet/